# Error in raster R package - Error in UseMethod("conditionCall")

Tags: r, r-raster

I'm using raster package to analyses some data (tif and asc files) but when I used "raster" function it returns:

```
cer2016 <- raster("cer2016.tif")
Error in UseMethod("conditionCall") : 
  no applicable method for 'conditionCall' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

I appreciate your answer.

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.